# Onde estou errando nesse joguinho de dados?

Tags: javascript, html

Fiz esse joguinho de dados bem porcão só pra exercitar http://jsfiddle.net/b02abznm/ (se possível abram no Dreamweaver ou outro editor semelhante, que no JSFiddle complica)

O único problema é que n consigo exibir o score de acertos dos 2 players.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar legível, veja se eu adivinhei bem o que você queria dizer.

Comment: @bigown, obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugestão:

```
var count = 0;
var p1_placar = document.getElementById('placar1'),
    p2_placar = document.getElementById('placar2'),
    p1_jogada = document.getElementById('campojogada1'),
    p2_jogada = document.getElementById('campojogada2'),
    side = document.getElementById('side');

side.onclick = function(){
    executar1();
};

function executar1() {
    document.getElementById('conte').value = count;
    if (count % 2 == 0) jogarr(p1_jogada, p2_jogada, p1_placar);
    else jogarr(p2_jogada, p1_jogada, p2_placar);
}

function jogarr(jogad, jogad2, plac) {

    var girar06 = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    var imgs = new Array(null, "side1.png", "side2.png", "side3.png", "side4.png", "side5.png", "side6.png");
    var pontos = plac.value;
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (girar06 == i) side.src = imgs[i]
    }

    if (jogad.value == girar06) {
        pontos++;
        alert('Vc acertou');
    } else {
        alert('Você errou')
    }

    count++;
    jogad.disabled = true;
    jogad.style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
    jogad.value = "";
    jogad2.disabled = false;
    jogad2.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    plac.value = pontos;
    return count;

} // end jogarr
```

O que eu mudei:

- retirei a função dentro da função
- uso onclick no JavaScript em vez do HTML
- reorganizei o código para evitar repetições de linha iguais dentro de if/else
- corrigi o erro que tinha quando usava `plac = plac + 1;` e como a variável tem um nome diferente `p1_placar` e/ou `p2_placar` não eram atualizadas.

#### jsFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ngg6arx/

**Nota:** para este código funcionar numa página HTML tem de colocar uma função onLoad, ou colocar o JavaScript no final do HTML, antes da tag `</body>`

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54209/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-onde-estou-errando-nesse-joguinho-de-dados)